# why ignores the header() function the result of my method?

Tags: php, pear

```
$result = $mail->send($recipient, $headers, $html);
    if($result === 1)
    {
        $report= "1";
        header("Location: objednavka.php?reaction=".$report);
      //echo("Your message has been sent!");
    }
    else
    {
        $report= "2";
        header("Location: objednavka.php?reaction=".$report);
      //echo("Your message was not sent: " . $result);
    }
```

if this mail function runs down the if statement decide that if it was successfull or not. If I use the echo() part it writes that Your message has been sent. But if I want to redirect the user to another page it doesnt work. Why? How can I call the header function successfully?

Comment: what happening? do you see any error? enable error reporting then you can see the error!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [PHP - header()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php):

*Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP.*

Comment: hm... so what does it mean in my case? How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to set a corresponding status code ([`header()`](http://php.net/header))

```
header("Location: objednavka.php?reaction=$report", true, 301);
```

Comment: @Akam Good point, thanks. I've only seen the `mail()` within the title

Comment: Yea, I used the PEAR Mail function here. So any idea how to redirect the user? oh, and I dont get any error. The mail successfully has been sent, so that function works correctly, only the redirecting doesnt want to work :/

Comment: you mean this?
if($result === 1)
    {
        $report= "1";
        header("Location: objednavka.php?reaction=".$report,true,301);
    }
    else
    {
        $report= "2";
        header("Location: objednavka.php?reaction=".$report,true,301);
    }
because it didnt help :/